# Windows 10 no sound when changing volume

Tags: realtek-hd-audio

I have Voicemeeter banana. My headset is plugged in the front panel on my pc.
I have installed v2.82 of the realtek ALC892 codec.
I want my headset to be at 40 volume (because it is the good balance I need so everything is perfect and I can keep voicemeeter banana at 0)

[So i go to the sound panel, but as soon as I change the volume of the realtek](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtYeC.png) (even just by touching the cursor) the sound stop working and I have to re-install drivers to make it work again (even by restarting computer)

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

The solution is way too simple. You have to unplug then re-plug your device into the rear panel. Apparently, realtek hd audio codec need to be triggered once it get installed (even if it was working before changin the volume).